# Что такое утечка памяти и почему она происходит?

Tags: java, c++

Утекает что? Какая-то часть кода или информация находящаяся в переменной?

Comment: Это когда память взял, а потом отдать забыл.  Но это актуально только в C.  В Java от шаловливых ручек юзера убрали указатели и ручное управление памятью, и утечки памяти невозможны благодаря сборщику мусора.

Comment: Ещё какие утечки возможны в java. Классический пример - реализация стека на базе массива.

Comment: @KoVadim - пример со стеком некорректен. Вы же не говорите об утечке памяти в Си, когда зарезервировали большой стек, но не используете его?  При повторном использовании старых ячеек стека весь мусор оттуда будет корректно убран.  Да, это может быть очень большой мусор. )

Comment: @KoVadim - Обратите внимание на слово "неконтролируемого" в определении термина "утечка памяти".  В Java всё остаётся под вашим контролем.

Comment: @KoVadim - то, что Вы имели в виду, более точно называется "the Java language equivalent of a memory leak".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

Если на пальцах:

Все программы в рамках популярных ОС представляют собой определенным образом структурированный набор данных и инструкций. ОС знает, как работать с этими наборами данных и инструкций, и делает это в некотором заведенном порядке. В рамках ОС для этого есть объект - процесс, который подгрузит приготовленные разработчиком инструкции и данные, будет определенным образом выделять под них время процессора, порождать другие объекты ядра ОС, которые тоже что-то делают.

Сами инструкции так же могут взаимодействовать с разными сущностями операционной системы, файловой системой, порождать потоки, с периферией, выводить что-то на экран, взаимодействовать при работе с оперативной памятью. Все эти ресурсы, или многие из них - разделяемые. Например, вывод на экран, т.к. экран один. Или работа с памятью, т.к. ее конечное количество. И все это делается через API ОС напрямую, или через какие-то обертки над этим API ОС.

И раз память можно выделять, ее следует и освобождать, т.е. уведомлять ОС, что этот участок памяти "свободен", и может быть отдан любому другому процессу под его нужды. Контроль за тем, нужна ли программе еще та или иная память остается на усмотрение программы, ОС этим, естественно, не управляет.

И раз управление выделенной на куче памятью находится на стороне программы, программа может быть построена так, что иногда будет уведомлять ОС о том, чтобы выделить ей какую-то память, но не уведомлять об освобождении.

В цикле это приводит к тому, что со временем объем используемой программой памяти начинает бесконечно расти.

Некоторые средства, которыми разработчик взаимодействует с API ОС, сами умеют определять, что та или иная область памяти может быть освобождена, а некоторые не умеют.
В Java этим занимается абстракция "сборщик мусора". 
В C++ управлением этим целиком на стороне разработчика.

Comment: Всё же обычно между выделением памяти и возвращением её ОС находится рантайм, который поддерживает абстракцию heap-памяти и список свободных блоков. Таким образом, возвращение происходит обычно не ОС, а рантайму.

Comment: И виртуальная память, доступ к которой и осуществляется через кучу, а уже затем на которой происходит маппинг реальной памяти)

Comment: Угу. Но ОС возвращается (и у неё же берётся) именно виртуальная память.

Answer (score 2):

[Утечка памяти - википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%F2%E5%F7%EA%E0_%EF%E0%EC%FF%F2%E8).

> Уте́чка па́мяти (англ. memory leak) — процесс неконтролируемого
>   уменьшения объёма свободной оперативной или виртуальной памяти
>   компьютера, связанный с ошибками в работающих программах, вовремя не
>   освобождающих ненужные уже участки памяти, или с ошибками системных
>   служб контроля памяти.

Что-то конкретное из этого непонятно?

Comment: Понятно.Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 2):

Это когда ты указатель настроил на определенный участок памяти, а потом не освободил его и поменял указатель на другой участок памяти.
В итоге ты потерял доступ выделенному участку памяти. Это и называется утечка памяти.
И как написали выше. Если постоянно запрашивать у ОС память программе и не освобождать, в конце - концов, может дойти до того, что у ОС не останется свободной оперативной памяти. Компьютер начнет глючить. и придется перезагружать. Ну это если совсем прямым и тупым текстом писать.